# why WooCommerce's "procced to checkout" button is disapeared after being hooked to a function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing a plugin to ask the user which option for delivery wants, options are "immediately", "5 weeks" and "8 weeks". I created an option select box on the cart page and I want to save the user's selected option in the wc session so on the checkout page, I read it and apply a desired discount on the order.

I have written these functions in the plugin file and installed it but now when the user goes to the cart page, there is no proceed to checkout" button!
Does anybody have any idea what is the problem?
Als,o I have tried to save the option selected by the user in the order's metadata using `$order->update_meta_data` and `update_post_meta` but it didn't work either.

```
// Add the delivery date field to the checkout page
add_action('woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'mytoosheh_add_delivery_date_field');
function mytoosheh_add_delivery_date_field() {
    echo '<div id="discount-select-container">';
    echo '<h3>' . __('زمان تحویل سفارش:', 'discount_select_option') . '</h3>';
    echo '<select id="discount-select" name="discount_select">';
    echo '<option value="1">' . __('تحویل فوری : ' . mytoosheh_get_delivery_date(3), 'mytoosheh_delivery_date_option') . '</option>';
    echo '<option value="5">' . __('پنج هفته : ' . mytoosheh_get_delivery_date(35), 'mytoosheh_delivery_date_option') . '</option>';
    echo '<option value="8">' . __('هشت هفته : ' . mytoosheh_get_delivery_date(56), 'mytoosheh_delivery_date_option') . '</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
}

// Save custom field data to order's data
add_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'save_delivery_date_to_order_data');
function save_delivery_date_to_order_data($order, $order_id){
    if (isset($_POST['mytoosheh_delivery_date_option'])) {

        $option_data = sanitize_text_field($_POST['mytoosheh_delivery_date_option']);

        //$order->update_meta_data('mytoosheh_delivery_date_option', $option_data);
        //update_post_meta($order_id, 'mytoosheh_delivery_date_option', $option_data);
        WC()->session->set( 'mytoosheh_delivery_date_option', $option_data );

        if ($option_data === "1") {
            $delivery_date_to_save = mytoosheh_get_delivery_date(3);
        } elseif ($option_data === "5") {
            $delivery_date_to_save = mytoosheh_get_delivery_date(35);
        } elseif ($option_data === "8") {
            $delivery_date_to_save = mytoosheh_get_delivery_date(56);
        } else {
            $delivery_date_to_save = "خطا در محاسبه";
        }
        //$order->update_meta_data('mytoosheh_delivery_date', $delivery_date_to_save);
        //update_post_meta($order_id, 'mytoosheh_delivery_date', $delivery_date_to_save);
        WC()->session->set( 'mytoosheh_delivery_date', $delivery_date_to_save );
    }
    else{
        echo "not set";
    }
}
```

Comment: The function `mytoosheh_get_delivery_date()` is missing from your code, so not testable…

Comment: for test you can add this function : 
'''
function mytoosheh_get_delivery_date($count){
retrun "1402-10-14"}
'''